# ASP.Net MVC4 display dynamic contents in _Layout.schtml

Tags: html, asp.net, model-view-controller, dynamic

My _Layout.schtml has code below for displaying some static text in the top area of the main page.

```
<div>
    <span>some text</span>
</div>
```

I want to display dynamic contents (based on info from a database table).
Basically, the table contains 4 columns: Selection, Text1, Text2 and Text3
If selection is 1, text1 should be displayed;
If selection is 2, text2 should be displayed;
If selection is 3, text3 should be displayed.

How can I achieve this?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `viewbag` element inside `ActionResult` that uses `_Layout.cshtml` as its master page.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   //Get database table value;
   var data = db.table...
   if(data.selection == 1)
      ViewBag.Text = data.text1;
   else if(data.selection == 2)
      ViewBag.Text = data.text2;
   else
      ViewBag.Text = data.text3;
   return View();
}
```

Retrieve that `ViewBag` inside `_Layout.cshtml`

```
<div>
    <span>@ViewBag.Text</span>
</div>
```